# Automatically closing idle windows in Gnome

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, gnome

Can open windows automatically close themselves if they have not been used for X seconds in Gnome?

For example, right now I have some Firefox windows and some other file browser windows etc open located in the back of this Firefox browser.

I would like them to close themselves if I have not touched them for two minutes. Can this be done? I'm wondering if xdotool can be used for this task?

Comment: Do you mean windows or tabs?

Comment: @terdon, windows.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically close windows after pause (touched or not) use:

```
firefox &
sleep 2m
kill %1
```

If you find how to test window activation try:

```
firefox &
while _i_do_not_know_what_
do sleep 2m
done
kill %1
```